# Python - install script to system

Tags: python, installation

how can I make setup.py file for my own script? I have to make my script global.
(add it to /usr/bin) so I could run it from console just type: scriptName arguments.
OS: Linux.
**EDIT:**
Now my script is installable, but how can i make it global? So that i could run it from console just name typing.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

EDIT: This answer deals only with installing executable scripts into `/usr/bin`. I assume you have basic knowledge on how `setup.py` files work.

Create your script and place it in your project like this:

```
yourprojectdir/
    setup.py
    scripts/
        myscript.sh
```

In your `setup.py` file do this:

```
from setuptools import setup
# you may need setuptools instead of distutils

setup(
    # basic stuff here
    scripts = [
        'scripts/myscript.sh'
    ]
)
```

Then type

```
python setup.py install
```

Basically that's it. There's a chance that your script will land not exactly in `/usr/bin`, but in some other directory. If this is the case, type

```
python setup.py install --help
```

and search for `--install-scripts` parameter and friends.

Comment: Ok, i did that you wrote. But after running: setup.py install i got:<br />
error: file '/home/ockonal/workspace/scripts/getkey.py' does not exist

Comment: Ok, i've already mady my script installable, but how can i make it global? I can't run it from console just name typing.

Comment: Where exactly was the script installed? If it's in /usr/bin, then setup.py works fine. Check your script's permissions - it should have +x permissions for everyone. The script in your project should have these persmissions, so that when it's copied to /usr/bin everything will be fine.

Comment: Yeah, now my script is in /usr/bin. I tried to do: chmod +x /usr/bin/scriptname.py. But after that there is still: comand not found for my script name in console.

Comment: The only other thing that comes to my mind is to check your PATH. Try running your script as /usr/bin/scriptname.py . If that works, but typing scriptname.py doesn't, then it's about PATH. Also, doublecheck that your script has #!/usr/bin/python in the first line.

Comment: And check permissions of your script in /usr/bin.  Is it executable?  Is it readable by everyone?

Comment: Note in unix-land file suffixes are part of the name. That is, foo.py and foo are different files. The command processor doesn't know of suffixes (that's the whole point of #! ). So if you want people to only have to type 'foo' and not 'foo.py' then name the file 'foo'.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question is quite old, but just in case, I post how I solved the problem for myself, that was wanting to setup a package for PyPI, that, when installing it with `pip`, would install it as a system package, not just for Python.

```
setup(
    # rest of setup
    console_scripts={
        'console_scripts': [
            '<app> = <package>.<app>:main'
        ]
    },
)
```

[Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42934570/4055389)

Comment: `<package>` should be listed in `packages` keyword parameter of *rest of setup* part