# How do I make a custom system command out of my Python program?

Tags: python, command-line, argparse, docopt

If I have a command-line program written in Python (specifically using [docopt](http://docopt.org) which uses argparse I think), and I want to run it as `my-program command1 args` instead of `python my-program.py command1 args`, what do I have to do? For now, this is for Debian-based OS (e.g Ubuntu).

I normally make my module a package so I already have `setup.py` but that doesn't grant me a free command.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

@pyrospade gave a very good link below. I am going to share my result.

Suppose we have

```
top-level-directory
    setup.py
    package/
         __init__.py
         cli.py
```

You can use `scripts=['package/cli.py']` if you want to access `cli.py` in the shell.

If you want to run as `my-cli`, you can use

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts':
        ['my-cli=package.cli:main']
}
```

Since I use `docopt`, I have this

```
def dispatcher(...)
def fun1(....)


def main():    
    arguments = docopt(COMMAND, version="xxxx")
    dispatcher(arguments)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can even put it under `__init__.py` by saying `['my-cli=package:main']` but again, you need a function called `main()`. But you can name it whatever you want. Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your program has a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Make the file executable:

```sh
chmod a+x my-program.py
```

Make a link with the desired command name:

```sh
ln -s my-program.py /usr/local/bin/my-program
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks Okay, so you make it executable, now how do you run it anywhere within your system?

Comment: Updated the answer...just symlink to your path

Comment: hmm that sounds about right to me now. :/ didn't remember this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So do we always do this in our install script? Can we leave this to something like, say, PIP installer? I don't think it has the functionality to do what I wish it could do.

Comment: You'll want to add a bash script to handle this.  See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874521/python-install-script-to-system

Comment: Great. Just finished it. I shared my current usage in my edit. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add the shebang (#!) and make it executable.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for more info.