# Python - Install a CLI utility with pip for being usable not just with virtual environments

Tags: python, pip

Suppose a CLI utility published in PyPI, downloadable with `pip`.

I want to install it for being usable not inside a virtual environment. With a virtual environment, the entrypoint script is being created in the `env/bin/` directory. But, installing it with `pip` with the virtual environment deactivated, it's just being installed in `/usr/local/lib/pythonX/dist-packages/<package-name>`, and without a `<package-name>` entrypoint script in the path, so it's not callable.

Is there a possibility to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - install script to system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874521/python-install-script-to-system)

Comment: If the package is yours, you can fix it with info above.

Answer (score 1):

You can always export `PYTHON_PATH` in your `.bash_[profile|rc]` file to manipulate which path to look for regardless of your virtual environment.

According to Python documentation on `PYTHON_PATH`:

> The default search path is installation dependent, but generally begins with prefix/lib/pythonversion (see PYTHONHOME above). It is always appended to PYTHONPATH.
>
> An additional directory will be inserted in the search path in front of PYTHONPATH as described above under Interface options. The search path can be manipulated from within a Python program as the variable sys.path.

source: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @gnis and @anatoly-techtonik, but I figured out to make it delegate to the setuptools, instead of creating scripts by hand.

It's just a matter of passing a dictionary to `setup`, `console_scripts`, which can be exactly the same as `entry_points` (the one that generates the file in the virtual environment `bin/`:

```
setup(
    # rest of setup
    console_scripts={
        'console_scripts': [
            '<app> = <package>.<app>:main'
        ]
    },
)
```

This will generate an script in `/usr/local/bin`.

For more info check https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#console-scripts

Comment: Feel free to add your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874521/python-install-script-to-system and make it more readable. I believe both questions are about the same. )

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will! Cheers